# Permission change after moving file?

Tags: bash, scripts, chmod

I want to run a bash script in a directory `/media/aliakbar/New Volume(internal drive)/further/path/to/file` .
The problem is: with **chmod +x** the file's permission is not changed (proof: I couldn't execute script from terminal):

```
-rw------- 1 aliakbar aliakbar    561 Jun  8 14:05 buildscript_0.10.0.sh
```

I moved the file to `/home/<user>/Downloads/`, did **chmod +x** which worked, and moved file back to `/media/aliakbar/New Volume(internal drive)/further/path/to/file`, replaced non-executable file but still with ls -l there's no change!?

**NOTE**: I'm on Ubuntu LTS 14.04 (dualboot) with `df -T` run in file directory returning:

```
/dev/sda3   fuseblk   277228568   168883892   108344676   61%   /media/aliakbar/New Volume
```

- `New Volume` is on an internal drive
- unfortunately I don't know how it's mounted, I have only an empty `/etc/fstab.d/` folder

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" ... You are forgetting to tell us what filesystem it is using and it better not be NTFS ;-) Or ... check the mount option used for that external disk...

Comment: Let me guess this is on a USB drive, right ? How did you mount it ?

Comment: no with _df_ i get this: `/dev/sda3      fuseblk  277228568 168883892 108344676   61% /media/aliakbar/New Volume`

Comment: How about this `sudo mount /media/aliakbar/New\ Volume    -o remount,rw,uid=1000` ?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi fuseblk = NTFS. NTFS does not understand file permissions from Linux. You provide the permissions when mounting when using NTFS.

Comment: df does not tell you filesystem type. Run `sudo blkid`

Comment: @Rinzwind ok, so what to do now?I'm new to linux so don't really know how to mount filesystems manually :/

Comment: @Serg `blkid` returns: `/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="CA9C196A9C1951F5" TYPE="ntfs"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, please tell us 1) what kind of drive this is, external or internal and 2) how it is mounted. Is it mentioned in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @terdon: edited

Comment: or see http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: @Rinzwind: thanks, but this comment is not answered so what do i put there for `/dev/whatever` and `/mnt/whatever` in my case? http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition#comment534753_11843

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi  /dev/sda3 , since this is what df output told you

Comment: @Serg: Thanks and what do i put for /mnt/whatever?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi /mnt/whatever is just folder  in /mnt folder.  Just create some folder in /mnt, call it some name, like folder1 , and put /mnt/folder1. If you call it folder2, you'd put /mnt/folder2. Understand ?